# How can I fix an inconsistent dll linkage?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

So I've gone over some previous mentions of inconsistent dll linkage and haven't been able to figure out why it's happening to me. I've seen mention of import/export but don't see that throughout the .h/.cpp files related.
What I get is:

PATH\file.h(27) : warning C4273: 'strlwr' : inconsistent dll linkage
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(247) : see previous definition of 'strlwr'

The header file in question has the following within the first 27 lines:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strlwr(char *string);
```

Does the declaration of strlwr here conflict with string.h? Of course there is a corresponding definition of strlwr inside of file.cpp. I know I haven't included a lot of information, so if I can include anything else that I haven't please feel free to tell me so.

And for reference, line 247 of string.h has: `_CRT_NONSTDC_DEPRECATE(_strlwr) _CRTIMP char * __cdecl strlwr(_Inout_z_ char * _Str);`

Comment: `strlwr` is a c function, and you declare your own?

Comment: @tobi303 That seems to be the case. I'm currently just going through fixing warnings, I wasn't actually the one to write the software. Is there a chance this should just be named something else?

Comment: i dont know any c. My guess would be that those macros make the true signature different from `char* strlwr(char*)`.

Comment: All right, thanks for your help. Sorry about not giving you much to go on.

Comment: You have a name collision with [ancient MSVC library function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235455.aspx).  Not part of the standard C library, but MSVC once supported the posix sub-system on WindowsNT and these function names started without an underscore back then.   Using `#define __STDC__` before the #include for string.h should prevent the compiler from seeing it.

Comment: @HansPassant What exactly does that do? 

Defined as 1 only when compiled as C and if the /Za compiler option is specified. Otherwise, undefined

Reading that didn't help me understand it. I did try adding it, however, and I got an error as well.

Comment: Just look at string.h to see how it is used.  These declarations are wrapped by `#if !__STDC__` so if it is #defined then the preprocessor skips them.

Comment: I see that now. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: So when I defined STDC as 1, I got the error about strupr identifier not found. This led me to just comment out the original declaration of strlwr inside of file.h. It seems to have removed all instances of dll linkage issues. I guess I should have thought to try that from the start but the warnings seem to be gone and the program compiles without error.